# Long time to Commit

Tags: github, github-for-windows, github-desktop

When I commit a sizable number of files (200 files) through GitHub for Desktop, it just sits there for a very long time (>10 minutes). It does eventually complete.

Scrolling through the debug log doesn't seem to show anything out of place.

This seems to be a recent development, as the previous Github for Windows did not seem to have this issue.

I'm currently on version `The Last Free Monad (3.0.5.2) a0622a5`, and my git version is `1.9.5.github.0`

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any binary files in your repository?  This slowness may be due to something somebody else did.

Comment: Also, try with a recent git for windows (2.6.1: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

Comment: There weren't binaries in the commit, but will try a newer version of Git, though I thought GitHub desktop upgraded Git as part of its upgrade.

Comment: Meant to reply to this earlier. Updating Git fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to the latest version of Git resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with GitHub Desktop is that it includes its own version of git for windows, and you cannot update/upgrade it. [I tried before and it didn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33703716/6309).

But it is also true that since Nov 2015, GitHub Desktop finally went from an old 1.9.5 version to a 2.5+ version, which, as noted by the OP, improves the situation.

Note that you can have [both GitHub Desktop and git for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35129798/6309) (with different versions).