# How to update git version from GitHub Desktop on Windows

Tags: windows, git, github, github-for-windows

I want to use the new `worktree` functionality introduced in [`git 2.5`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree). However, I don't know how to update to the most recent version of GitHub Desktop (*not* git itself).

I install [GitHub for desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) and hoped it ships with the most recent version, however `git --version` returns `git version 1.9.5.github.0`. But if I understand correctly, we're already at version 2.6.x! So how can I update to this version on my Windows machine, where the only version of git I installed was with the GH Desktop?

Comment: I have edited my answer to add a caveat about git system settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update Nov. 25th, 2015.
For what it is worth, GitHub Desktop (finally) uses a more recent git version: 2.5. See [Brendan Foster tweet](https://twitter.com/shiftkey/status/669375487681040384).

---

Original answer (early Nov 2015)

First, the latest git for [windows release is available here on GitHub](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).
I always use the archive portable form (unzipped anywhere I want, and added to the `PATH`).

But if you have chosen the `exe` setup, that means it has been installed in `C:\Program Files\Git`.

However, [as I mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11928949/6309), git is also included in GitHub Desktop own installation path (`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\GitHub\PORTAB~1\bin`)

You could, in theory, replace the exact value of the folder PORTAB~1 by a directory JUNCTION:

```
cd %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\GitHub
dir # take note of the exact name of PORTABLEGIT folder: <PORTAB...>
move <PORTAB...> old_PORTABLEGIT
mklink /J <PORTAB...> "C:\Program Files\Git"
```

In my latest GitHub Desktop 3.0.7.1 3397ae4, I see:

```
C:\Users\vonc\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c2ba306e536fdf878271f7fe636a147ff37326ad\bin
```

However, that would not work: when starting GitHub Desktop again, it would detect the change and restore its own embedded Git version (1.9.5)

So you can't force easily GitHub Desktop to use another git version.

---

Even if you were able somehow to force GitHub for Desktop to use another version of Git, you would have to carefully report its own internal git system configuration:

```
 C:\Users\vonc\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c2b...\etc\gitconfig
```

This file points to GitHub Desktop specific settings:

```
[http]
        sslcainfo = /bin/curl-ca-bundle-ghfw.crt
[credential]
        helper = !github --credentials

[filter "ghcleansmudge"]
        clean = cat
        smudge = cat
```

THose settings are *not* present in a non-GitHub embedded version of Git, and would need to be restored.

Comment: So, in conclusion: *So you can't force easily GitHub Desktop to use another git version.*?

Comment: @BramVanroy Exactly. You can confirm with GitHub support, but the way I see their product, they worked really hard to keep their own git version, and prevent any "tinkering".

Comment: Not that I put a lot of effort in trying to contact them, but I didn't get an answer on a tweet I sent them unfortunately. Thanks for figuring things out!

Comment: @BramVanroy By the way, GitHub Desktop now uses git 2.5! See my updated answer.

Comment: O yes! Thanks a lot! Gonna try it out, and how that worktree functionality is "allowed"

Comment: This is a problem with security updates of Git. It's too bad that GitHub is tied so tightly. Today, my Secunia PSI warned me of minor vulnerabilities in 2.11.0 (which is probably the "A potential but unlikely buffer overflow in Windows port has been fixed." in 2.11.1. I now have to wait for GitHub folks to integrate that fix. Lately, I've been using Source Tree (Atlassian) more and more for this and many other reasons.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator I agree. I always use the "System" Git in Source Tree, ie the one I can point to (which is the latest one at https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

Comment: It's happened again. I'm surprised GitHub is using a version of GIT that ends in `.0` -- see screen shot here: https://imgur.com/SZRDZrz

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Is that the embedded Git packaged with GitHub Desktop?

Comment: @VonC yes, in `AppData\Local\GitHub\`

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Windows Git installer here: http://www.git-scm.com/

For best results, I suggest uninstalling Github desktop, installing Git (which you downloaded from the above link), and reinstalling the Github client.

Comment: Hm, unfortunately this doesn't work. I did as you said, and the git version used by GitHub Desktop is still the 1.9.5 version. Git has been installed, though, because when I run git --version in the newly installed git folder from the bash command, it returns 2.6.3.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `worktree` why don't you install [MSYS2](https://msys2.github.io/) ?
*MSYS2 is a fork of mSysGit which is not maintained anymore*
It's like a unix console and you can update your own git version thanks to [Pacman](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pacman) which is a package manager from Archlinux

I hope you'll find this helpful !
Regards

**EDIT** : If you only want to use "Git For Windows", [here](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/) is the last release which comes with Git v2.6.3.

Comment: I could simply use the git shell to use the latest git version, the problem is that I want to use the most recent version INSIDE GITHUB DESKTOP.

Comment: So here is what you need : [Git 2.6.3](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/)

Comment: Not Git for windows. Github for Desktop.

Answer (score -1):

The instructions describing the [steps required to update github for windows](https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/getting-started/updating-github-desktop/) are listed here:

1. In the upper-right corner of the **Github for Windows**, click the icon that looks like a little gear or cog (see image example).
2. Choose **About GitHub Desktop** from the menu initiated when you clicked the icon in step 1.
3. If an update is available, you will be permitted to click **Restart to install update.**
4. here is the link to [all the steps screen grabbed off the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziXaM.jpg) on imgur

Comment: That's not the question. I need to use an updated version of git inside the app