# Github Desktop windows sync button disappears and history tab is not working

Tags: button, github, crash, synchronization

I am using GitHub Desktop version 3.1.1.4 on Windows 7 Professional 64 Bit

- For some reason, history tab does not work. It shows changes tab display only.
- Sync button is not there any more.

I tried following:

1. Restarting PC
2. Reinstalling Git for windows version 2.9.0.windows.1
3. Closed all other application

I have attached screenshot of GitHub Desktop for both changes and history tab:

Changes tab:
[image: changes tab]

History tab:
[image: history tab]

Anyone else faced similar issue? Any suggestion what else I can try to resolve this issue?

Comment: I've had almost the same problem for a couple of months now. The sync button is there, but pressing it just starts an animation that goes forever. The history tab issue is the exact same.

Comment: Haaahahah... I recently reinstalled the entire OS, and for a while this worked fine. Now the same problem is back, though... There's something weird going on for sure.

Answer (score 0):

> Reinstalling Git for windows version 2.9.0.windows.1

That doesn't change anything for [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/): it uses its own embedded distro of git for Windows, and [you cannot change it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33703716/6309).

Try first to see if the issue persits with:

- another new repo (git init test2, make a few commits)
- another cloned repo (git clone https://github.com/git/git for instance), then [add it to your GitHub Destop](https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/contributing/adding-a-repository-from-your-local-computer-to-github-desktop/)

Comment: I tried both cases but getting some result. The top bar where sync button resides disappears (turns into black). Yesterday I reinstalled Github Desktop then it started working but suddenly it crashed today and now it is having same issue.

Comment: @TusharMehta Strange: so you see anything in GitHub Desktop logs?

Comment: @TusharMehta "|HardwareRenderingHelper|Your video card appears to support hardware rendering. If this isn't the case and you see glitches", maybe a video pilot driver issue?