# git add -p in Windows Git Shell, child_info_fork::abort

Tags: git, powershell, github

In Windows Git Shell, I could use `git add -A`.

But when I try to use `git add -p` and the error shows as follows:

`1 [main] perl 10436 child_info_fork::abort: C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\usr\bin\msys-perl5_22.dll: Loaded to different address: parent(0xC40000) != child(0xFF0000)`

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PortableGit_xxx` means you are using an outdated Git package with [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/). And [you cannot upgrade it directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33703716/6309).

Try instead the same git add -p in a simple CMD session, with:

- the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) unzipped anywhere you want (as C:\Git 2.12.2.2)
- the `PATH` correctly set to that Git version

That is:

```
set GH=C:\path\to\git2.12.2.2
set PATH=C:\windows\system32;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```